# Is a Wick rotatable spacetime necessarily strongly causal?

Tags: complex-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, general-relativity, lorentzian-geometry, obstruction-theory

There are a few viable ways to formulate Wick rotatability that preserve distinct features.

One is mentioned in the post:

[Obtain Lorentzian manifolds from Riemannian ones by Wick rotation](https://mathoverflow.net/a/165345/503363)

There's also the paper by Helleland:
[Wick rotations and real GIT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.04576)

By [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/462046/503363) one knows that *strong causality and pure electricity are two orthogonal conditions at each generic point $p$ of a manifold $M$.*

My personal question is

if any of these definitions of Wick Rotatability(specially that of Helleland) imply that a Wick Rotatable spacetime is Strongly Causal.

Bearing in mind that a [Wick rotatable metric, is necessarily purely electric](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.01244)

one can oppositely ask for a counter example where:

if there's any Wick rotatable spacetime(so also purely electric) that is not strongly causal as a counter example.

I'd be more curious about the 3+1 dimensional case which is realistic.

A **weaker version of the question** would be:

Can a CTC contaning spacetime be Wick Rotated?

---

PS: I am trying to check if the obstruction to the Wick rotation can be of topological nature, since there's a topological mismatch between manifold topology and the Alexandrov topology(observable topology) in case of time-oriented spacetimes that are not strongly causal.